# Firefox bug: Javascript function won't automatically activate

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, carousel

I'm working on image carousel that automatically rotates between slides. It works perfectly in Chrome, however I'm having an issue in Firefox.

In order for the carousel to start rotating, I have to run a javascript function called "begin_carousel()".

Currently, I just include an html node that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">begin_carousel();</script>
```

And include it after including my

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="carousel.js"></script>
```

I've also tried running the begin_carousel() function within the carousel.js file, but firefox still won't initiate that function. Or perhaps, it doesn't like how the function is constructed. Here's the code for begin_carousel():

```
var iFrequency = 6000; // expressed in miliseconds
var myInterval = 0;
var count = 0;

// STARTS and Resets the loop if any
function begin_carousel() {
    if(myInterval > 0) clearInterval(myInterval);  // stop
    myInterval = setInterval( "change_carousel()", iFrequency );  // run
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why Firefox might not like this javascript? Or is there some different way Firefox handles javascript as opposed to chrome? Answers would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: open firebug, and check the console for errors.

Comment: Have you tried putting "begin_carousel()" in "$(document).ready()" (or if you arent using jQuery into window.onload or body.onload? )

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` nor `setInterval` with strings, because it's like evil `eval`! Use functions instead: `setInterval(change_carousel, iFrequency)`